# Text Field Alignment with Label

Tags: html, css

I would like my label aligns with corresponding textfield. However snippet code that I posted here, returns me the following UI. Actually first row  (20 --> First) is the right format that I want to implement.

[image]

Updated Figure based on Rafael answer. I have limited space to display these elements. It seems to me that wherever I have more than 6 characters, it does not fir into allocated space. But I do not how to fix

[image]

```
 input[type="text"]{
        display:inline;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-right:3px;
        width: 50px;
        text-align:center;
        clear: left;
}    


label {
       color: white;
       display: inline-block;
}

ul {
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
} 


<ul>
<li><label for="first">First</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="firstTF"/></li>
<li><label for="second">Second</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="secondTF"/></li>
<li><label for="third">Third</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="thirdTF"/></li>
<li><label for="fourth">Fourth</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fourthTF"/></li>
<li><label for="fifth">Fifth</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fifthTF"/></li>
<li><label for="sixth">Sixth</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="sixthTF"/></li>        <li><label for="seventh">Seventh</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="seventhTF"/>  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your label after your input, couldn't you? And then, remove the `float: left` from the inputs.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckLj90Le/1/)

If you don't want to change the order of the elements, you could add an `overflow: hidden` to your `li`, like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckLj90Le/2/)

**Edit**

About your edit: that depends on how you want to solve it. What do you want to do when the text is bigger than the space that you have to display it?

You could, for instance, set a max-width and hide any text that overflows it, like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckLj90Le/3/)

Comment: Hello Rafael, I have implemented you code and run it. Please see what I have got on my updated figure.

Comment: By the way, I have limited space to display these elements. It seems to me that wherever I have more than 6 characters, it does not fir into allocated space. But I do not how to fix.

Comment: Then you could decrease your `margin-right:3px;` of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Here comes the expected results :

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">

input[type="text"]{
        display:inline;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-right:3px;
        width: 50px;
        text-align:center;
        clear: left;
}    

label {
       color: black;
       display: inline-block;
       text-align: right;
       float: right;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
} 
</style>    

<ul>
<li><div id="ligne"><label for="first">First</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="firstTF"/></div></li>
<li><label for="second">Second</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="secondTF"/></li>
<li><label for="third">Third</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="thirdTF"/></li>
<li><label for="fourth">Fourth</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fourthTF"/></li>
<li><label for="fifth">Fifth</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fifthTF"/></li>
<li><label for="sixth">Sixth</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="sixthTF"/></li>        
<li><label for="seventh">Seventh</label><input type="text" value="Loading..." id="seventhTF"/>  </li>
  </ul>
```